# Qt 5.1 portable

Tags: qt, portability

Please help me find a portable version of Qt 5.1.1 for Windows 32-bit. If there is none available, please tell me how to create one. I've never done it, so I'll need a step-by-step instructions.

Thanks in advance!
Baha

Comment: Hello! Yes, I am totally new to programming in Qt though have some skills in C++ console programming. All I wanted is to be able to use Qt 5.1 in my corporate network without installing it. Just copy into a folder and run it. Surely, there must be someone experienced in making portable versions of applications.

Answer (score 3):

Qt is not portable, they're dumb enough to hardcode the install path not only into config files, but into BINARIES too.

You can create a `bin/qt.conf` file though, e.g.

```
[Paths]
Prefix = c:/lib/Qt/4.8.5
```

Then check the result with `bin/qmake.exe -query`, it should show the given path in the config file.

Too bad 4.8.5 [crashes](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-35275) when qt.conf is present, and there's no 4.8.6 yet...

Answer (score 1):

All Qt versions are supposed to be portable - it is the nature of this framework. You can find desired binary version of Qt [here](http://qt-project.org/downloads).

Comment: That is not really true. You may mean within the same major version. Surely, Qt 4 to Qt 5 is not portable, etc. A good answer should also explain that even that Qt 5 provides guarantees binary compatibility for its Qt 5.X series, it might be that certain functionality is missing or buggy on another machine. These are very short replies, not covering the real answer in details.

Comment: @LaszloPapp, when I talk about being portable, I assume that the the same source code can be built and run in different environments, and this is pretty much fits both Qt 4 and 5. Even if the answer is short, it corresponds to the question, which is short as well.

Comment: If we assume too much, at times people would not need to ask questions. A real answer should be way more elaborative, especially when there is a question like this where the OP seems to be a complete newcomer.

Comment: @LaszloPapp, I think that your previous comment is rather rude, so that I am free to simply ignore it. If you find you know better, please provide your answer too with comprehensive analysis of whatever you want.

Comment: Sure, this is not a good answer in my book, so I will try to write one after my work. Newcomers need a bit more hand-holding.

Answer (score 0):

Portability is not at binary-level but at source-level. It means that you can port an application written in standard C++ and Qt among different platforms (e.g., Windows, Linux, Mac, and so on).

Comment: Erhm, you think portability includes binary break? Not that Qt 5 has it (it does not by mission statement), but still, your answer reads wrong due to that.